# Many to many database design

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database-design

I have `Person` and `Course` that have many to many relationship. (There is a table that maintains the relationship with just the 2 IDs

Is it better to have a 3rd boolean field `Selected` for that relationship.

Or add/remove the complete rows from the relationship table?

What is more common? I need to support editing as well

Comment: what would be the purpose of the SELECTED field?

Comment: It's better to remove the rows from the relational table in order to save spaces, especially if you don't have any details on the relational table

Comment: what i understood from your question is that you want to delete/keep relationships from a pivot table. Am I right? If I am right then it depends on your business logic. If the requirement is to keep the track of all the history then you have to keep them.

Comment: The answer depends on how this table fits into your overall database design, what data you need to store, and what you are storing in other tables.  Based on your question, other possible fields in that table could be Role (student, instructor, etc), and Status (registered, in progress, completed, etc).

Comment: @DanBracuk at the moment I dont have any additional information to store on the relationship. I only care to see the courses the this person has enlisted. Maybe I didnt use a good example but think of search tags that are linked to an entity. I am also using a WebAPI to return those courses like a check-list. Where the user can select which of those courses apply.

Comment: If you're using a SELECTED field, your table will have to have Count(Person) * Count(Course) rows in it. After a while that will become very unwieldy and will make adding/deleting rows from either table extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

It's better to remove the rows from the relational table in order to save spaces, especially if you don't have any details on the relational table